# Why doesn't enter key work in my php pages posts?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to edit my php page and i have an option to add posts. After I enter whole text and click post my whole new text shows without enters, in one piece without pharagraphs. I tried using shift+enter and adding  in the end of pharagraph.
Any ideas what is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: `enter`s are newline characters when the content of a <textarea> or <input type="text"> field is sent to the server but should be converted to <br/>s to be displayed as newlines in an HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

You should try and use the [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br) method.

Works a little something like this:

```
echo nl2br($text_from_post_field);
```

What it does is the following:

Returns string with `<br />` or `<br>` inserted before all newlines `\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<br>"
```

This will go to the next line if you are trying to break up the lines with space between them.

```
\n
```

is also the forced line break in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Use P tag and BR tag.
check http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp
and http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Comment: Well, I tried to use p and br and what happens is, tags post as piece of text and that's it.
The thing is that i can post only from admin page and i don't have access to the pages code.